# Rank/Order/Cluster/Sort Data Frame by Column Pattern

Tags: r, sorting, rank, bipartite

I have a data frame called df1 like so:

[image]

I wish to re-order the columns of df1 such they group by matching a column pattern. This means that any column that has all 1s in all rows groups to the far left. Then any column that has a value of 1 for row A and row B, but 0 for row C, should follow...and so on, like in df2 below.

[image]

If there are ties (and there are many in my dataset), it does not matter, as long as they group/cluster according to their column pattern. For example, in df2, if column ex2 & ex5 are switched in order, or [edit after comments below] column ex3 & ex6 are switched in order, it's also an acceptable solution for me...

I tried ranking by column sum at first, but that obviously doesn't work, bc the ties where the sum is 2 results in columns that shouldn't be adjacent "clustering". For example, I'll get ex3, ex6, ex3, ex3, ex6 in a "cluster", when I want all that look like ex3 together, and all that look like ex6 together. It should be ex3, ex3, ex3, ex6, ex6.

I thought to iterate through each column, and pattern match to the patterns of 1s and 0s I desire, but I'm really lost on how to pattern match against the whole column and not just a value in a column.

Code is below:

```
ex1 <- c(1,0,0)
ex2 <- c(1,1,1)
ex3 <- c(1,0,1)
ex4 <- c(0,1,0)
ex5 <- c(1,1,1)
ex6 <- c(0,1,1)
ex7 <- c(0,0,1)
ex8 <- c(1,1,0)

df1 <- data.frame(ex1,ex2,ex3, ex4, ex5, ex6, ex7, ex8)
rownames(df1) <- c("a", "b", "c")

df2 <- data.frame(ex2, ex5, ex8, ex6, ex3, ex1, ex4, ex7)
rownames(df2) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: would the values be only 0 and 1? can you explain the logic behind `ex6` and `ex3` ? Why is `ex6` ahead of `ex3` ? Do you want to order them based on number of 1's in column?

Comment: Just a very quick idea, how about creating a clustered heatmap object e.g. `h <- heatmap(as.matrix(df1))` and then using the row and column orders to create your new data frame so `df2 <- df[rev(h$rowInd), rev(h$colInd)]` ?

Comment: Is this _really_ your actual problem or is it just a toy example since that does matter for the solution. A solution for 3 rows and the "factor" combos you said are the order may be different than a more generic one.

Comment: Values are only 0 or 1 (@Ronak Shah). ex6 and ex3 can be interchanged in order...I'm not clustering columns based on sums of 1s in the column, but on them having the same patterns of 1s and 0s in the same rows...
I have "interaction" data (an incidence matrix?). A 1 represents an interaction btw protein ex7 with bacterial "strain c". I'm trying to cluster all the interactors that interact similarly with the strains together, so that the heatmap that I made (@Joe) is clearer to read. I can then see which proteins interact similarly amongst strains. This is a toy example (@hrbrmstr).

Comment: @Joe If I use a heatmap, they don't cluster the way I need them to. What does the rev function do with respect to the data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1[,order(
  factor(
    apply(df1, 2, function(x) paste0(x, collapse="")), 
    levels = c("111", "110", "011", "101", "100", "010", "001", "000")
  )
)]
##   ex2 ex5 ex8 ex6 ex3 ex1 ex4 ex7
## a   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
## b   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
## c   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
```